# How to prevent tags and scripts from executing in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am using prepared statements from Mysqli. This takes the input as text and submits it as text, preventing SQL injections.

The problem arises when I read text from database. The text I read executes in the browser!

For instance - if I write as input:

```
<b>Hello</b> how r u?<br>
<script> alert('He is fine dnt wry!') </script>
```

This goes into the database as it is. But when I read it back from the database using my `SELECT` query, and display it, instead of displaying, my `<b>` tags and `<script>` tags get executed!

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` maybe?

Comment: If you wish to accept HTML, clean it up with HTML Purifier, or consider accepting a different language. Markdown is popular, and there are several parsers available in PHP for it.

Comment: Depends on what you want.  http://php.net is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo htmlentities("<b>Hello</b> how r u?<br>
<script> alert('He is fine dnt wry!') </script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code before rendering the code to screen.

```
string htmlspecialchars_decode ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 ] )
```

his function is the opposite of htmlspecialchars(). It converts special HTML entities back to characters.

Check out the manual [here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: But why Decode?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php
Answer here shows something different?

Comment: I suspect this is wrong. If the dev wants to accept text (and not HTML) then `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` is appropriate in the template file, so that angle brackets are output as entities. If there dev wants to accept HTML, then the HTML needs to be cleaned, or accepted as Markdown (or similar) and then converted to HTML.